# Why to use hook_drush_help() when we have 'description' in hook_drush_command()?

Tags: drush

When you go to create new drush commands you can define the 'description' element inside the `hook_drush_command()`, and if you use `drush help your_command` you will see this description as output.

```
function onlyone_drush_command() {
  $items['onlyone-list'] = array(
    'description' => dt("List the configured content types to have Only One node."),
    'aliases' => array('ol'),
    'examples' => array(
      'drush onlyone-list' => dt("List the configured content types to have Only One node."),
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Command:

```
drush help ol
```

Output:

```
List the configured content types to have Only One node.

Examples:
 drush onlyone-list  List the configured content types to have Only One node.

Aliases: ol
```

But once you implement the `hook_drush_help()` and you use `drush help your_command` you will see the description defined inside this hook and you'll never see again the description defined inside `hook_drush_command()`.

```
function onlyone_drush_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'drush:onlyone-list':
      return dt('This is from help');
  }
}
```

Command:

```
drush help ol
```

Output:

```
This is from help

Examples:
drush onlyone-list  List the configured content types to have Only One node.

Aliases: ol
```

So, why to use `hook_drush_help()` when we have 'description' in `hook_drush_command()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *context*.

The command data pulled from `hook_drush_command()` is used when listing of all available drush commands with the command:

```
drush
```

So if a user is curious, "What drush commands do I have, and what do they do?" `hook_drush_command()` would provide that snippet. This could be useful for a short description in a directory of commands.

If a user is curious about a specific command:

```
drush help my_command
```

That's where `hook_drush_help()` would be more applicable as it can provide a detailed description that is only about that command queried.